# fullcalendar google event shown but no name

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm using google calendar to display events using fullcalendar, however they all show 
[like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziiHq.png)

When I click on one of those lines they do redirect to the correct event in google calendar - So the events are recognised. I've used lots of different javascript examples but they all do the same, this is the basic one i've been using:

`$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'myAPI',
    events: 'myCalendarID'
  });
});`

I also copy pasted one of the full calendar demos (and changed my API key) but it still displays the same as the image above.

Comment: Silly question but do your google calendar events actually have names / descriptions? Also...have you checked your browser console for errors? Have you inspected the HTML to see if the descriptions are present in the HTML, but just not visible? It seems from the screenshot you may have customised your CSS...perhaps you've inadvertently caused the problem that way? Try removing your custom CSS and using the standard fullCalendar CSS instead. To summarise: you need to do some debugging. Just from the generic setup code you've shown it's completely impossible to give a direct answer.

Comment: I spent so much time but didn't once think about my other massive CSS file conflicting, thanks for the help - relieved so much of my frustration!